# Optional parameters in mule cloud connector

Tags: parameters, mule, option-type

I want to build a processor in my custom cloud connector using @Optional and @Default, like so:

```
@Processor
public void createTopic(String topicName, @Optional @Default("defaultSecurity") String security, @Optional @Default("defaultDialect") String dialect) throws Exception{

}
```

However I cannot get the java to compile, is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem using your `@Processor` definition in one of my connectors so you must be missing something:

- Do you use the right annotations, ie `org.mule.api.annotations.param.Optional` and `org.mule.api.annotations.param.Default`?
- Do you have proper JavaDoc on the method?
- Do you have a documented example for the method?

If yes to all, then please specify what error you're receiving when running `mvn generate-sources`.